# how to automatically highlight in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to automatically highlight text by selecting, so I select the words `Bob is Cool`.

I want notepad++ highlight every other `Bob is Cool` words, like find, if I select the number 0, I want notepad++ to highlight all the numbers 0, when I unselect 0, it removes the highlight.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://superuser.com/questions/1274554/notepad-highlight-occurrences-of-selected-text

Comment: @frippe thats exactly what i needed, Thx